# MySQL using IN/FIND_IN_SET to read multiple rows in sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery, in-subquery

I have two tables, locations and location groups

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    location_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(63) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO locations (name)
  VALUES
('london'),
('bristol'),
('exeter');

CREATE TABLE location_groups (
    location_group_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    location_ids VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_ids VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO location_groups (location_ids, user_ids, name)
  VALUES
('1', '1,2,4', 'south east'),
('2,3', '2', 'south west');
```

What I am trying to do is return all location_ids for all of the location_groups where the given user_id exists. I'm using CSV to store the location_ids and user_ids in the location_groups table. I know this isn't normalised, but this is how the database is and it's out of my control.

My current query is:

```
SELECT location_id 
  FROM locations 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(location_id, 
      (SELECT location_ids 
         FROM location_groups 
         WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,location_groups.user_ids)) )
```

Now this works fine if the user_id = 1 for example (as only 1 location_group row is returned), but if i search for user_id = 2, i get an error saying the sub query returns more than 1 row, which is expected as user 2 is in 2 location_groups. I understand why the error is being thrown, i'm trying to work out how to solve it.

To clarify when searching for user_id 1 in location_groups.user_ids the location_id 1 should be returned. When searching for user_id 2 the location_ids 1,2,3 should be returned.

I know this is a complicated query so if anything isn't clear just let me know. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Don't give up! Fight for normalization!

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the `location_id`s in the subquery.

```
SELECT location_id 
FROM locations 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(location_id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(location_ids)
     FROM location_groups 
     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,location_groups.user_ids)) )
```

Alternatively, use the problems with writing the query as an example of why normalization is good. Heck, even if you do use this query, it will run more slowly than a query on properly normalized tables; you could use that to show why the tables should be restructured.

---

For reference (and for other readers), here's what a normalized schema would look like (some additional alterations to the base tables are included).

The compound fields in the `location_groups` table could simply be separated into additional rows to achieve [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), but this wouldn't be in [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), as the `name` column would be dependent on only the `location` part of the `(location, user)` candidate key. (Another way of thinking of this is the `name` is an attribute of the regions, not the relations between regions/groups, locations and users.)

Instead, these columns will be split off into two additional tables for 1NF: one to connect locations and regions, and one to connect users and regions. It may be that the latter should be a relation between users and locations (rather than regions), but that's not the case with the current schema (which could be another problem of the current, non-normalized schema). The region-location relation is one-to-many (since each location is in one region). From the sample data, we see the region-user relation is many-many. The `location_groups` table then becomes the `region` table.

```
-- normalized from `location_groups`
CREATE TABLE regions (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(63) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

-- slightly altered from original
CREATE TABLE locations (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(63) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

-- missing from original sample
CREATE TABLE users (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(63) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

-- normalized from `location_groups`
CREATE TABLE location_regions (
    `region` INT UNSIGNED,
    `location` INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`region`, `location`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`region`)
        REFERENCES regions (id)
        ON DELETE restrict ON UPDATE cascade,
    FOREIGN KEY (`location`)
        REFERENCES locations (id)
        ON DELETE cascade ON UPDATE cascade
);

-- normalized from `location_groups`
CREATE TABLE user_regions (
    `region` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `user` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`region`, `user`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`region`)
        REFERENCES regions (id)
        ON DELETE restrict ON UPDATE cascade,
    FOREIGN KEY (`user`)
        REFERENCES users (id)
        ON DELETE cascade ON UPDATE cascade
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO regions
  VALUES
('South East'),
('South West'),
('North East'),
('North West');

INSERT INTO locations (`name`)
  VALUES
('London'),
('Bristol'),
('Exeter'),
('Hull');

INSERT INTO users (`name`)
  VALUES
('Alice'),
('Bob'),
('Carol'),
('Dave'),
('Eve');

------ Location-Region relation ------
-- temporary table used to map natural keys to surrogate keys
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE loc_rgns (
    `location` VARCHAR(63) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    `region` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
);

-- Hull added to demonstrate correctness of desired query
INSERT INTO loc_rgns (region, location)
  VALUES
('South East', 'London'),
('South West', 'Bristol'),
('South West', 'Exeter'),
('North East', 'Hull');

-- map natural keys to surrogate keys for final relationship
INSERT INTO location_regions (`location`, `region`)
  SELECT loc.id, rgn.id
    FROM locations AS loc
      JOIN loc_rgns AS lr ON loc.name = lr.location
      JOIN regions AS rgn ON rgn.name = lr.region;

------ User-Region relation ------
-- temporary table used to map natural keys to surrogate keys
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE usr_rgns (
    `user` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `region` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`user`, `region`)
);

-- user 3 added in order to demonstrate correctness of desired query
INSERT INTO usr_rgns (`user`, `region`)
  VALUES
(1, 'South East'),
(2, 'South East'),
(2, 'South West'),
(3, 'North West'),
(4, 'South East');

-- map natural keys to surrogate keys for final relationship
INSERT INTO user_regions (`user`, `region`)
  SELECT user, rgn.id
    FROM usr_rgns AS ur
      JOIN regions AS rgn ON rgn.name = ur.region;
```

Now, the desired query for the normalized schema:

```
SELECT DISTINCT loc.id
FROM locations AS loc
  JOIN location_regions AS lr ON loc.id = lr.location
  JOIN user_regions AS ur ON lr.region = ur.region
;
```

Result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```